# How to reverce field mysql

Tags: mysql

I have table `war`:

```
--------------------------------------
| ID | MEMBER_ID | RIVAL_ID | RESULT |
|------------------------------------|
| 1  |     1     |     2    |    1   |
|------------------------------------|
| 2  |     3     |     1    |    1   |
|------------------------------------|
```

I want to retrieve the current result and its reversed result in a query as follows

```
--------------------------------------
| ID | MEMBER_ID | RIVAL_ID | RESULT |
|------------------------------------|
| 1  |     1     |     2    |    1   |
|------------------------------------|
| 2  |     3     |     1    |    1   |
|------------------------------------|
| 1  |     2     |     1    |    0   |
|------------------------------------|
| 2  |     1     |     3    |    0   |
--------------------------------------
```

To reverse `RESULT`, I used the `ABS()` function but I can not query as desired
I tried creating the VIEW tables then the query but also not correct.

Can I do that? Give me any idea

Comment: Use `NOT result` or `1 - result`

Comment: @Barmar I want to reverce MEMBER_ID with RIVAL_ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can take a union of a query which selects all the original records in the `war` table with another query which also selects all rows, but reverses the `MEMBER_ID` and `RIVAL_ID` columns, as well as swaps 0 and 1 in the `RESULT` column.  One more trick we might need to generate your exact output would be to add a computed column to the union query which keeps track of each half, with the original records all appearing above the swapped records.

```
SELECT t.ID, t.MEMBER_ID, t.RIVAL_ID, t.RESULT
FROM
(
    SELECT ID, MEMBER_ID, RIVAL_ID, RESULT, 1 AS position
    FROM war
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        ID,
        RIVAL_ID,
        MEMBER_ID,
        CASE WHEN RESULT = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
        2
    FROM war
) t
ORDER BY
    t.position,
    t.ID
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester